# Would an armbian question be on-topic here, even if it is running on a different board?

Tags: discussion, support

would this question:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462785/armbian-dm-raid-module-has-gone-missing

be on-topic here? In fact, the actual machine running the armbian is not a Raspberry Pi (but an Orange Pi PC 2), but I could just go and plug the SD card into a Raspberry Pi and have the very same problem. I'm confused whether this is an acceptable question here. Would it be acceptable if I in fact encountered the problem on a Raspberry Pi? Or if I reproduced it there?

Thanks,

Lukas

Answer (score 5):

If not actually on the Raspberry Pi it would be off-topic. Or as the [helpcenter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has it: **Please make sure that your questions are intrinsically Raspberry Pi oriented.**

Once you put it in a RPi and it still is a problem it will be on-topic here.

Note however that it is never appropriate to cross-post the same question across different sites of the Stackexchange network. It would seem that it is on-topic on U&L so your best bet is to keep it there.